gitflow extension for VS2022
I'm using this extension since VS2022.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-57624.GitFlowforVisualStudio2022
If I execute form VS2022 "Finish release" function isn't the editor shown to be able to write the message to the merge commit on main?
while if I execute the same command but from prompt
git flow release finish "0.1.0.0" -n -k
Does the commit message editor open without any problems?
some advice on how to solve the problem using VS2022
